# Assembly on Windows

Tags: assembly, compilation, nasm, cpu-registers, mingw-w64

i'm was studying about cpu architetures for study the assembly language, but i have this doubt because many tutorials on yt i see peoples using a based Linux distribution to create, compile,and run assembly code.

can you help me? thanks!

I'm was trying to compile the .asm using the NASM, bt when i run it, it "sleep" for seconds and stop the execution, i'm was seeing and try testing with Mingw, but has the same problem.

i'm was searching in very sites and videos but i can't find it

i'm try using: `nasm -f win32 App.asm`  and `gcc App.obj -o App.exe` to compile it to an exe

and `.\App.exe` to run

Comment: You might like sample program [cpmix](https://euroassembler.eu/prowin32/cpmix32.htm), which can be assembled and linked at once and which creates a graphic program for Windows.

Comment: Microsoft Visual Studio lets you do assembly on Windows. And even if you're using C its inline assembly syntax is much more straightforward than GCC's.

Comment: Keep in mind that Windows and Linux use different syscalls, if you see `int 0x80` in the code, it won't run on Windows correctly. That's a Linux operation.